# show CheckedOutByUser Items sitecollection level in sharepoint 2010

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am trying to pull checked-out items at site collection level. Whenever the user login with his credentials he needs to see all his checked out documents at site collection level.(Whatever the items he has checked out in sub-sites and so on). As of now I am using content query web part and customized it to show the checked-out items by me but the problem is it is showing the items when I click on it it is opening the item directly but I need to go to location how to configure this in CQWP SharePoint 2010. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling the data you want and you are familiar with modifying data view web parts, I would suggest creating some custom xsl for the CQWP. Where the link to the document is now, you could instead use the folder path as the href. Here is a two part article that explains at a high level how to customize the xsl for the CQWP

[cqwp-and-xslt-part-1](http://paylord.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/cqwp-and-xslt-part-1/)

[cqwp-and-xslt-part-2](http://paylord.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/cqwp-and-xslt-part-2/)

If you aren't getting all the data through the CQWP, then use the the search web service in conjunction with [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) and javscript to write your own display.

Comment: Murphy i have used the same procedure to make custom xslt and updated but am getting the items required the only thing is it is directly opening the item . is there a way to add a column to take me to the file location .

Comment: You could use fileleafref and substring to change the href to the folder instead of the file name.

Comment: I have tried using  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(@FileLeafRef),'.')"/> but it is only giving me the name of file its not clicakble nor taking me to the location of the file

Comment: I want to get the path or location of the file in the web part .any suggestions on the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work:<a>
     <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@FileRef,@FileLeafRef)"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef" />
    </a>

Comment: hi murphy do i need to mention anything on fields to display for fileref and fileleafref because I am not getting the location of the file. it is directly opening the file as said earlier same case no change in result. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are not replacing the href. Find where that is being set and replace it with the substring-before statement I have above.

Comment: I have replaced the existing <a href="{@FileRef}" target="{@LinkTarget}" title="{@LinkToolTip}"><xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'"><xsl:attribute name="onclick"><xsl:value-of select=""@OnClickForWebRendering"/></xsl:attribute> with your snippet